# The non-nullable local variable 'title' must be assigned before it can be used. Flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, non-nullable

I want to take user input from the `textfield widget` and assign in `title` variable as in this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function callBack; // function

  AddTaskScreen({required this.callBack});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String title; // declaring the variable
    return Container(
      height: 350,
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Add Task',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              autofocus: false,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                title = value; // taking the user input
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                hintText: 'Type a Task',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 12,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                callBack(title); // error
              },
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see there is a function `callBack` variable. it has the `String` parameter when I pass `title` in this function it gives me a warning.
here is the code for the callBack when will send this information.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todoey/models/Task.dart';
import 'package:todoey/screens/add_task_screen.dart';
import 'package:todoey/screens/bottom_section.dart';
import 'package:todoey/screens/top_section.dart';

class TasksScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TasksScreen> createState() => _TasksScreenState();
}

class _TasksScreenState extends State<TasksScreen> {
  List<Task> tasks = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                child: AddTaskScreen(
                  callBack: (String taskTitle) {
                    setState(() {
                      print(taskTitle);
                      tasks.add(
                        Task(
                          name: taskTitle,
                        ),
                      );
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ).build(context),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 35,
        ),
        elevation: 5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TopSection(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            BottomSection(tasks: tasks),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

for the main class, here is the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todoey/screens/task_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: TasksScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter, you want to store mutable objects (such as your `title`) in a `State`. This is because the build function can theoretically be called many times, you have no control over it. Therefore, storing the variable in the `State` of an object allows you to keep it "alive" while `build` is called many times.

Here is your example, adapted to work as intended:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function callBack; // function

  AddTaskScreen({required this.callBack});

  @override
  State<AddTaskScreen> createState() => _AddTaskScreenState();
}

class _AddTaskScreenState extends State<AddTaskScreen> {
  /// Declare title in the state, so that its a long lived object
  var title = ""; // Initialize it (likely as empty)
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      height: 350,
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Add Task',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              autofocus: false,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                title = value; // taking the user input
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                hintText: 'Type a Task',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 12,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                widget.callBack(title); // error
              },
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are using a stateless widget and so you `onChanged` function will not work because the state of a stateless widget will not change to render the new value of the *title*, so you could change it to a stateful widget to see the effect.

Comment: I thought about it, but I have not tried it. I will try it. because I am watching the tutorial that angela teach in udemy, I think her code worked like what I have written.